# How to use matplotlib.pyplot.show to order histograms based on custom order?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

When I use `plt.show()` to view multiple histograms, the histograms are shown in terms of alphabetical order. I am trying to order the histograms according to my selection.

```
viz = cdf[['D','C','B','A']]
viz.hist()
plt.show()
```

I want the order D, C, B, A

[image: Histogram order shown]

Comment: [subplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot), example:https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#logarithmic-and-other-nonlinear-axes

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = 'D','C','B','A'

plt.hist(X)
plt.show(
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try [subplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot):

```
# A
plt.subplot(224)
...
# B
plt.subplot(223)
...
# C
plt.subplot(222)
...
# D
plt.subplot(221)
...
plt.show()
```